# Images are vertical instead of horizontal

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I can't get my images to align horizontally. Instead they align under one another.
I am making this code from [W3Schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tab_img_gallery.asp).
I tried flex, float and other solutions on the web.
I am making this for my homepage to showcase some of my photos.

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.column img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  width: 150px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.column img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
}

#imgtext {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 15px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="F35C Parked" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="F16 Venom" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/150/150" alt="EuroFighter Landing" onclick="myFunction(this);">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <span onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none'" class="closebtn">&times;</span>

  <img id="expandedImg" style="width:100%">

  <div id="imgtext"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.row {display: flex;}
```

That's all you need.